# PureScript Node.FS.Sync readTextFile returns garbage

Tags: node.js, purescript

In simplest JS I have:

```
const {readFileSync} = require('fs')
console.log(readFileSync('test.csv','utf8'))
```

Works as expected. I try to reproduce it in PureScript:

```
module Main where
import Prelude
import Effect.Console (log)
import Node.Encoding (Encoding(UTF8))
import Node.FS.Sync (readTextFile)
main = do
  text <- readTextFile UTF8 "test.csv"
  log text
```

Logs unreadable garbage to console. Why? What I do wrong?

**EDIT**

Turns out the garbage is returned only in `pulp repl` mode and only for non-latin chars. It has nothing to do with `Node.FS.Sync (readTextFile)`. And `log "ФЫВА"` in `pulp repl` also produces garbage.

Comment: That actually works just fine for me. Can you show the compiled JS for this? What version of PureScript are you using?

Comment: @FyodorSoikin I use 0.13.2. I just compiled it with `pulp build -O > out.js` and tested it with `node out.js` and it worked correctly. The incorrect output is logged only in `pulp repl`. Don't know how to paste compiled js in comment, it's ~200 lines. I just realized - only non-latin chars are displayed incorrectly. Maybe that's the reason.